# Unusual hits from Amazon application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have multiple Amazon application and elastic load balancers with multiple servers behind them. Issue is load balancer flush requests to servers with urls like

```
    app-0 (out): info: GET /administrator/pma/ 200 1261.343 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /administrator/PMA/ 200 1287.396 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /administrator/admin/ 200 1180.192 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpMyAdmin2/ 200 1184.603 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpMyAdmin3/ 200 1262.463 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpMyAdmin4/ 200 1297.300 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpMyAdmin-3/ 200 1188.261 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /php-my-admin/ 200 1183.684 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /PMA2011/ 200 1258.948 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: HEAD /PMA2013/ 200 1290.279 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: HEAD /PMA2014/ - - ms - -
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /PMA2015/ 200 1182.416 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /PMA2016/ 200 1261.733 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /PMA2017/ 200 1289.620 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /PMA2018/ 200 1185.837 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2011/ 200 1178.948 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2012/ 200 1229.194 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2013/ 200 1320.295 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2014/ 200 1185.979 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2015/ 200 1180.451 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2016/ 200 1181.597 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2017/ 200 1271.013 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /pma2018/ 200 1185.556 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2011/ 200 1224.569 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2012/ 200 1177.819 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2013/ 200 1261.961 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2014/ 200 1184.600 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2015/ 200 1186.763 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2016/ 200 1177.270 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2017/ 200 1253.435 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmyadmin2018/ 200 1300.840 ms - 19185
    app-0 (out):
    app-0 (out): info: GET /phpmanager/ 200 1184.614 ms - 19185
```

There are plenty of more urls like these. I dont have sql or anything like this installed on my server. This chokes my server some times. Port 80 is not directly opened on server. Only Loadbalancer is allowed to access server using port 80

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374756/how-to-handle-aggressive-http-requests-from-the-same-ip

Comment: But why is your server returning 200. are you sure no other process running on your server. I have see this in the past someone hacked into our server and started minecraft server and we started seeing too many http requests

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to fix this in the ELB itself. The reason this chokes your server is that your application actually seems to process the request and takes quite a while to do that (over 1 second) which probably consumes a lot of CPU power and maybe even memory (it all depends on the application of course).

You might be able to mitigate the issue by putting some kind of filter or caching layer in front of your ELB (services like CloudFlare might be able to handle this) to reduce the load on your servers. You can also introduce some logic to your webserver to ensure these calls are not passed to your application. Lastly, you could also make sure these calls don't overload your setup by either ensuring this request triggers a 404 message (it probably should) and 404 messages are prompt and lightweight, or by (auto-)scaling your setup (scaling up could be an actual short-term solution until you can fix it in another manner, if preventing downtime is the main concern).

Answer (score 0):

This attack signature looks like [Jorgee](https://blog.paranoidpenguin.net/2017/04/jorgee-goes-on-a-rampage/). It is a type of vulnerability scanner.  Here are my logs from a Jorgee scan on my servers:

```
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/administrator/PMA/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/administrator/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpMyAdmin2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpMyAdmin3/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpMyAdmin4/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpMyAdmin-3/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/php-my-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2011/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2012/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2013/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2014/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2015/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2016/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2017/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/PMA2018/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2011/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2012/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2013/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2014/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2015/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2016/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2017/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/pma2018/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2011/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2012/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:36:50 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2013/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:37:00 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2014/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:37:00 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2016/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:37:00 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2017/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:37:00 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmyadmin2018/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
Sep 20 09:37:00 "HEAD http://x.x.x.x:80/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 Jorgee"
```

That article has some suggestions, but they all work at the server level, and not at the ELB level.

You cannot block access using security groups, as they do not have a deny mechanism, only allow.

You could try to auto block IPs by using Network ACLs using a custom fail2ban filter.

Answer (score 0):

There's some solution on AWS Elastic Load Balancer level I had in my applications. We've had a problem with AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment reporting health warnings with messages like `requests to the ELB are failing with 5xx`. We investigated the problem and that was because of `Jorgee` bot and some more standard scanners.

What I did was basically creating Web ACL with rule using `string condition` to match `Host` header with some defined domain for my application. So if bot tries to request ELB with its IP address (which they typically do), it gets 403. No more health warning on EB environment level and we still can track these requests easily with Cloudwatch, so we know what's going on with bots still.

There's some guidance I did on https://www.mkubaczyk.com/2017/10/10/use-aws-waf-block-bots-jorgee-500-status-elastic-beanstalk with step by step instructions to create such a rule. Hope it helps! It just requires AWS Application Load Balancer, but that's not a big problem as you can easily create new environment with eb-cli using `--elb-type application` flag. :-)